# login control and admin panel encryption from mere users

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i am working on a project that has two types of users i.e admin and mere users. now i want to ensure that the mere users cannot access the admin pages by entering the url for admin.php or any other admin pages once they log in. the problem is on my login.php code for i allow them both to use the same login page caption. i have the login.php below, maybe the help could be on how i can work with my if statement to control that or the sessions.

```
        <?php 
        session_start();

        include_once("connect.php");

        $un = $_POST['un'];
        $pw = $_POST['pw'];

        mysql_select_db("pp",$con);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$un' AND password='$pw'";

        $result= mysql_query($query);

        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))



        {

        if ($row['role']=="user") {

            $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;
            header("Location: employee_home.php");


            }

        else { header("Location: admin.php");
        $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;}   

        }

        else { header("Location: index.php?log=error"); 
        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check roles.

```
**Type**    **Role**
User 1    1(Users)
User 2    2(Admins)


    if ($row['role']==1) {
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;
        header("Location: employee_home.php");
        }
    else if($row['role']==2) { 
       header("Location: admin.php");
       $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;}   
    }
    else { header("Location: index.php?log=error"); 
    }
```

And in admin.php, check if user role is < 2 then, redirect to error page or access denied page.

Basically, you need to put conditions in admin.php also.

Comment: in my admin.php i have this session code 
<?php session_start(); 
//ob_start()
if ($_SESSION['loggedIn']!=1) {header("Location: index.php");}
?>

Comment: if (!empty($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && ($_SESSION['loggedIn']==2)){ // write your code here }

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate

[Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831994/how-to-prevent-access-of-admin-pages-by-knowing-the-admin-page-url)

```
<?php
  session_name('MyAdminSession');
  session_start();

  if (isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if ($userid == 'myusername' && $password == md5('mypassword')) {
      $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
      header('location: admin.php');
      exit;
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: hey, thats for one user only admin. am working on one login page directing two users i.e admin and mere users

Comment: @mountain have two values in session & include a common file to all admin page in which if session is not available then redirect to login page.

Comment: i have worked it out. the session control is the best. 

<?php session_start(); //ob_start() if ($_SESSION['loggedIn']!=2) {header("Location: index.php");} ?> with 2 being for admin session.

Comment: @mountain ok good work...